# Android studio: Unable to store a file in External in built storage overriding the sd card

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie to Android. I have a simple question which I searched over the internet and found no answer.

I want to store a text/picture on an *external inbuilt storage* even when the SD card is available on the device.

I tried the following command.

```
File[] externalFilesDirs = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
for(File f : externalFilesDirs){
Log.d("tag","device list:"+f+"\n");
}
```

The above command is returning me only one storage location. I.e., the SD card location. I want it to list all the location and I should be able to select one one location from the list and store my txt/jpg doc in *that* location.

FYI, i already know the fact that Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), you can access both locations by calling getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: `The above command is returning me only one storage location. I.e., the SD card location. `. Hard to believe. That would give as first item external storage and as second, if micro sd inserted, path to private directory on micro SD card. Please tell exact full path you got.

Comment: But if you just want to use external memory (no sd card) then use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().

Comment: `Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), you can access both locations by calling getExternalFilesDirs().`. Yes. But be aware that on a lot of 4.4 devices this is implemented wrong. Blame the manufacturers.